# Why is $2^{2^2}$ so much less than $2^{2^{2^2}}$?

Tags: exponentiation

I assume there's a name for raising something by an exponent repeatedly, but I haven't been able to find it. I understand why $2^{2^2} = 16$ and $2^{2^{2^2}} = 65536$ by plugging in the numbers, but I am having trouble building some intuition for why the former is so much smaller than the latter; $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$ can't even be handled by my calculator, for instance.

Comment: Cf. [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Comment: I think you got your header backwards.

Comment: The sequence is defined recursively by $x_0 = 1$ and $x_{n+1}= 2^{x_n}$.  When we take $2^{\textrm{large number}}$ we get an extremely large number.  So it makes sense that this sequence grows ridiculously fast.

Comment: Try to see it that way: if you write numbers in base $2$, then your sequence can be described by "the next number is 100...000, where the number of zeroes is equal to the current number". In base $10$, that would mean: $10$, then 10000000000 (already big), and the next number is 100....000 with ten billion zeroes. You can see that it grows pretty fast.

Comment: Woops, fixed the header.

Comment: The notation is ${}^32=16$ (`{}^{3}2=16`) etc.

Comment: Hint: write them in binary. What's $2^{2^2}$ in binary? What's $2^{2^{2^2}}$? EDIT: Oh, Captain Lama got there first

Comment: @CaptainLama that's perfect, thanks!

Comment: Why is $n$ so much less than $2^n?$

Comment: $2^n$ counts all the subsets of $\{1,2,\,n\},$ while $n$ counts the subsets of size $1.$ There are a lot more subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume there's a name for raising something by an exponent repeatedly, but I haven't been able to find it.

There is indeed a term for that; it's called **tetration**

It might be easier to wrap your head around the concept if you use 10 instead of 2.

$10^{10}$ is a 1 with ten zeroes after it. Go ahead and write that on a piece of scrap paper real quick. (it equals ten billion if you're wondering)

$10^{10^{10}}$ is a 1 with **ten billion** zeroes after it. If you wrote one digit every second, it would take you **300 years** to finish writing!

Answer (score 1):

The name you are looking for is "tetration" or "hyper-$4$". It is a hyper-operator, indeed.
Tetration is the operator such that "addition : multiplication = multiplication : exponentiation = exponentiation : tetration", even if we lose some properties climbing the aforementioned ladder (e.g., $2 + 3 = 3 + 2$, $2 \cdot 3 = 3 \cdot 2$, while $2^3 \neq 3^2$, and also $^{2}3 \neq ^{3}2$, since $2^{\left(2^2\right)} \neq 3^3$).

Now, you can think that we are calculating those giant numbers as $^{5}2$ solving the power tower from top to bottom, so that $^{4}2$ becomes the exponent of $^{5}2$ and $2^{65536}$ is about $2.003529930 \cdot 10^{19728}$, which is a number with almost $4000$ times the digits of $^{4}2$.

Now, we can understand why $^{6}2$ is as big as $10^{{6.031226063} \cdot 10^{19727}}$.